# How do I split a list of integers into a list of digit integers?

Tags: python, integer

Consider the list

```
test_list = [14, 12, 10, 8]
```

I want to remake/split this into

```
test_list = [1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0, 8]
```

I want to split the list into single digits.

Comment: And, what have you tried to achieve the same? See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand Shivam Jha. Do you have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Here, you provide your code, so that others can help you for any problem in it. You should provide it too... so we can help you with any difficulties in them.

Comment: Ok, sorry. The problem is that I don't neccessarily have a code yet, only a problem. New to this forum.

Comment: I suggest to read the link provided in the first comment to understand the guidelines, and so that your concerns and questions are well understood and received by the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? (you want to split the integers)

```
newList = [int(y) for x in test_list for y in list(str(x))]
```

Comment: @FrodeWilkensen welcome. If you liked the answer then click the large check mark to accept it as the answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - iterate over the numbers in your list, and for each number, split into a list of digits, each element of which is appended to a digits array.

```
digits = []

for num in test_list:
    digits.extend([int(i) for i in str(num)])
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit tricky one:

```
b = [int(digit) for digit in ''.join((str(item) for item in a))]
print(b)
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach that doesn't employ a string as an intermediary:

```
test_list = [14, 12, 10, 8]

output_list = []

for number in test_list:
    if number < 10:
        output_list.append(number)
    else:
        output_list.extend([number // 10, number % 10])            

print(output_list)
```